# PDF items are not getting indexed and not listed in multilist with search

Tags: solr, indexing, pdf

I have upgraded Sitecore 8.1 to 9.1 and now in 9.1 PDF items are not getting indexed and also they are not getting listed in a multilist with search field.

Comment: Did you include pdf template in index file? What is a root path of index?

Comment: Which index are you using? Azure/Solr,? And which one were you using on 8.1?

Comment: currently solr and with 8.1 Lucene

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing the needed IFilter to index pdf content. Check https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-pdf-files.html for the information on 9.1:

> The Sitecore Content Search API uses the native Microsoft Windows
>   IFilter interface to extract the text content from media files for
>   indexing.
>
> However, to enable the Sitecore Content Search API to properly index
>   the content in Adobe PDF files, you must install the Adobe PDF IFilter
>   on every content management and content delivery server.
>
> Currently, Sitecore only supports Adobe PDF IFilter version 9.
>
> You can install Adobe PDF IFilter as a standalone IFilter or as part
>   of Adobe Acrobat Reader. You can download Adobe PDF IFilter version 9
>   from ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/9.x/.